# How can I decode CBOR-encoded data that uses CBOR byte strings in Java?

Tags: java, go, jackson, fasterxml, cbor

I am sending CBOR-encoded data from one application to another. The application receiving the CBOR-encoded data is a Java application. The CBOR-encoded data was encoded with strings as byte strings, i.e., [CBOR major type 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8949.html#name-major-types).

I thought I could do this with [`com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/latest/index.html), but I did not find any support for decoding byte strings with this library.

I am able to decode the data in Go, using the code below. However, I am not free to change the language the application I am working on from Java to Go.

```golang
decMode, err := cbor.DecOptions{
    ByteStringToString:    cbor.ByteStringToStringAllowed,
    DefaultByteStringType: reflect.TypeOf(""),
}.DecMode()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
err = decMode.Unmarshal(b.Bytes(), v)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Is there a different Java library that does have support for decoding CBOR byte strings? Or does `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor` support this, and I just failed to find details for their support in their documentation?